# How to drag data to next line?

Tags: excel, vba

Good afternoon,

I have a table where column A has the customer's data and column B has the customer's name. In columns C to L  have the invoice information for that customer. I would like to get a vba code for when there is data in column A and B, create a row above the total and drag 1 row down the invoice information, looking like this:

A2 and B2 with the customer's code and name;

C3:L8 with customer invoice information;

Line nine: Total line (I already have this code)

```
Sub table_customer()

Range("A1:L1").Select
Selection.Borders(xlDiagonalDown).LineStyle = xlNone
Selection.Borders(xlDiagonalUp).LineStyle = xlNone
Selection.Borders(xlEdgeLeft).LineStyle = xlNone
Selection.Borders(xlEdgeTop).LineStyle = xlNone
With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeBottom)
    .LineStyle = xlContinuous
    .ColorIndex = 0
    .TintAndShade = 0
    .Weight = xlMedium
End With
Selection.Borders(xlEdgeRight).LineStyle = xlNone
Selection.Borders(xlInsideVertical).LineStyle = xlNone
Selection.Borders(xlInsideHorizontal).LineStyle = xlNone
With Selection.Interior
    .Pattern = xlSolid
    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorDark1
    .TintAndShade = -0.349986266670736
    .PatternTintAndShade = 0
End With
Range("A1").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Code"
Range("B1").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Customer"
Range("C1").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Type Doc."
Range("D1").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Reference"
Range("E1").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Data doc."
Range("F1").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Due date"
Range("G1").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Currency"
Range("H1").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Value eur"
Range("I1").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "days delay"
Range("J1").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "overdue v"
Range("K1").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Obs."
Range("L2").Select
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("L1:L2"), Type:=xlFillDefault
Range("L1:L2").Select
Range("A2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "123"
Range("B2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "kkk"
Range("C2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "qq"
Range("D2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "qq"
Range("E2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "qq"
Range("F2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "qq"
Range("G2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "qq"
Range("H2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "qq"
Range("I2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "qq"
Range("J2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "qq"
Range("K2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "qq"
Range("C3").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "tt"
Range("D3").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "tt"
Range("E3").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "tt"
Range("F3").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "tt"
Range("G3").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "tt"
Range("H3").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "tt"
Range("I3").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "tt"
Range("J3").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "tt"
Range("K3").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "tt"
Range("C4").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "yy"
Range("D4").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "yy"
Range("E4").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "yy"
Range("F4").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "yy"
Range("G4").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "yy"
Range("H4").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "yy"
Range("I4").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "yy"
Range("J4").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "yy"
Range("K4").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "yy"
Range("C5").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "pp"
Range("D5").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "pp"
Range("E5").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "pp"
Range("F5").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "pp"
Range("G5").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "pp"
Range("H5").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "pp"
Range("I5").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "pp"
Range("J5").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "pp"
Range("K5").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "pp"
Range("A6").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Total"
Range("A6:K6").Select
Range("K6").Activate
With Selection.Interior
    .Pattern = xlSolid
    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorDark1
    .TintAndShade = -0.349986266670736
    .PatternTintAndShade = 0
End With
Rows("6:6").Select
Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
Range("C2:K5").Select
Selection.Cut Destination:=Range("C3:K6")
Range("C3:K6").Select
End Sub
```

[image]

According to the print, the objective is to move the information in order to obtain the line (which is currently in yellow). That's the ultimate goal.
Currently, I have the information 1 line above, the information being right in front of the customer's names. As you can see, not all customers have the same number of invoices. My idea is that the vba code should read the cell of column A that has the "Total", then add a row above the total row, and finally shift the information down.

Comment: Have you tried using the record button to start the VBA macro command?  What does the recorded macro code look like?

Comment: @zipzit I put the code in the question above, please check

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Before you read this keep in mind the last time i actively programmed is like 4 years ago. Means the code is messy, not optimized, blah blah blah**

So as requested to get a list like this:

[image]

to a format like this:

[image]

you can use the following code snippet. The "CommandButton1_Click()" function is only there because I use it as my trigger from a userform. the "adjustList" method can be called from wherever you like.

Basically I read all the customer data blocks into two dimensional arrays and clear the cells. After all entries are collected in the array and all cells are clear i write the data into the cells again with the requested format.

Also as requested this function can handle entries independent of how many rows they contain per customer, as shown in my screenshots.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Call adjustList
End Sub

Function saveEntry(x As Integer, y As Integer) As Variant
    Dim tmpRows()
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim e As Integer
    Dim numOfRowsForEntry As Integer
    Dim numOfColumns As Integer
    numOfColumns = 10
    Dim tmpColumns() As String
    ReDim tmpColumns(numOfColumns)

    Cells(x, 1).Select
    numOfRowsForEntry = 0
    Do Until ActiveCell = "Total"
        Cells(x + numOfRowsForEntry, 1).Select
        numOfRowsForEntry = numOfRowsForEntry + 1
    Loop
    
    ReDim tmpRows(numOfRowsForEntry - 1)
    
    For i = 0 To UBound(tmpRows) - LBound(tmpRows)
        For e = 0 To numOfColumns
            tmpColumns(e) = ""
            tmpColumns(e) = Cells(x + i, y + e).Text
            Cells(x + i, y + e) = ""
            Cells(x + i, y + e).Interior.Color = xlNone
        Next
        
        tmpRows(i) = tmpColumns
    Next
    
    saveEntry = tmpRows
    Exit Function
End Function

Sub adjustList()
    Dim x As Integer
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim startRowOfList As Integer
    Dim entryList()
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    startRowOfList = 2
    NumRows = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    
    ReDim Preserve entryList(0)
    Cells(startRowOfList, 3).Select
    
    i = 0
    For x = startRowOfList To NumRows
        Cells(x, 1).Select
        If Not IsEmpty(ActiveCell) And Not ActiveCell = "Total" Then
            entryList(i) = saveEntry(ActiveCell.Row, ActiveCell.Column)
            ReDim Preserve entryList(UBound(entryList) - LBound(entryList) + 1)
            i = i + 1
        End If
    Next
    
    Cells(startRowOfList, 1).Select
    For x = 0 To UBound(entryList) - LBound(entryList) - 1
        For i = 0 To UBound(entryList(x)) - LBound(entryList(x))
            If entryList(x)(i)(0) = "Total" Then
                ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0) = entryList(x)(i)(0)
                For e = 0 To 10
                    ActiveCell.Offset(1, e).Interior.ColorIndex = 15
                Next
            Else
                ActiveCell = entryList(x)(i)(0)
                ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1) = entryList(x)(i)(1)
            End If

            For c = 2 To UBound(entryList(x)(i)) - LBound(entryList(x)(i))
                ActiveCell.Offset(1, c) = entryList(x)(i)(c)
            Next
            
            ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
        Next
        
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    Next
        
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: You know @Beatriz it would really help if you could show how you expect your result to look like, just an example of it. Its kinda hard to understand what format you expect...

Comment: Thank you for your availability @Nikita! Please confirm my update above, I put a print to make it easier to see.

Comment: I'll have a look at it later today.

Comment: I adjusted my answer according to the new data you have provided. I hope it helps you with your task!

Comment: Many thanks for your help! I have a question...My table header starts at row 9 and I have currently added one more column to the table. What are the changes in vba code? Can you help me? I've already made several changes (like trial and error) and I haven't been able to make the changes I wanted. Thank you!!

Comment: I adjusted the code in my answer a bit to better explain it. In line 47 you have the variable "startRowOfList" which defines the start of your table you want to format. There you have to set the start AFTER the header line (If you have your header in line 1 you set the variable to 2). and in line 11 you can adjust the number of columns you have. You have to set the actual number of columns you have - 1 (so if you have 11 columns you set this variable to 10).

Comment: Thank you so much, you are helping me a lot @Nikita!! 
One last question...in column A, instead of "Total", it appears the customer number followed by the total, such as "1234567 Total" (customer codes are 7 characters long). What can I change/add in the code so that the macro can run? I tried to change on line 56 and 66 to this: "******* Total" and then to this: "####### Total", but it didn't work...

Comment: You can use `ActiveCell Like "*Total"` instead of `ActiveCell = "Total"` this matches with any number of any characters in front of the text "Total". This is called a Regular Expression. There are a lot of tutorials that explain way better than me how to use them but in vba you need the "Like" keyword to check if a String matches your pattern. This is just one way to solve this but in my opinion it is the easiest. You would need to change this in the 3 lines where the text "Total" is hard coded (17, 56, 66).